# gRPC: Cannot create new servicesBases, gives error CS0246

Tags: c#, grpc, .net-6.0

I´m trying to create a service for a grpc_server but I have problems creating one and on top of that, I watching 2 tutorials and gives same error...

So my problem is creating a new Service, this is the proto I create

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "Grpc_Server_1.Protos";

package banana; //put 'Banana' but still gives error in the service

service Banana {
    rpc AddBanana (Z) returns (Y);
}

message Y {
  //3 strings
}

message Z {
  //2 strings
}
```

And this is the Service but it gives me a error idk why

```
public class BananaService : Banana.BananaBase //CS02468 The Type or namespace 'Banana' 
                                               //could not be found ... 
{
        // I have nothing here, just to see how strange the error is
}
```

I check also the GreeterService (this one works perfect if I remove all code except the public class or stick with the code) and I don't understand the error

What I need to do more to don't have this error?? I'm using .NET 6 VS2022

Any answer is welcome

Comment: And what do you have on `Banana.BananaBase`?

Comment: Banana.BananaBase i think thats should be ok with using more code cuz the 2 tutorials i see they call the methods in that form without create a Base (ex: they call [protoname].[protoname]Base or [protoname]Base and work perfect idk why, and this should give a error), if I put Greeter.GreeterBase that works fine cuz its from GreeterService but it not makes sense

Comment: Bananas class inherits from Banana.BananaBase, remove `:  Banana.BananaBase` from your class definition.

Comment: Did you include the namespace `Grpc_Server_1.Protos`?

Comment: @Ray the namespaces are all ok, in Protos either in the protos file or in the services

Comment: @McNets I remove but now, how in the client Project call my service if I don't have a Base or either a serviceClient? Because I need to create my var client but i don't know how to do

Comment: You need to build the project at least once to generate the code-behind c# base class with the namespace, if you just create the proto file but never call the protoc compiler you will not have any generated code that you can derive from in the service implementation